# SQL - joining two records in one

Tags: sql

I have a view and table. In the view I'm trying to pick-up the folio # and a from the table the related folio but then re-joining to the view to get the related folio #.

My query is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  A.FOLIOID
                ,A.FOLIOTYPE
                ,A.NAME
                ,A.FOLIONUMBER
                ,B.FOLIOID AS SUBFOLIOID
                ,B.FOLIONUMBER AS SUBFOLIONUMBER
FROM VW_FOLIO AS A
INNER JOIN FOLIOREF B ON B.FOLIOPARENTID = A.FOLIOID
INNER JOIN VW_FOLIO C ON C.FOLIOID=B.FOLIOID 
WHERE A.FOLIONUMBER='2018-01-01'
```

It gives me this result

```
FOLIOID       FOLIOTYPE   NAME         FOLIONUMBER    SUBFOLIOID     SUBFOLIO
ad61e75a5bcc  DOORS       JOHN BROWN   2018-01-01     bfdbf0bc9f24   2018-03-01
ad61e75a5bcc  DOORS     JOHN BROWN   2018-01-01     fbf4370a4d46   2018-03-15
```

The FOLIOREF table looks like this:

```
FOLIOREFID       FOLIOID       FOLIOPARENTID
1c489c11e8dd    bfdbf0bc9f24    ad61e75a5bcc
ece462200c59    fbf4370a4d46    ad61e75a5bcc
```

I think the question would be how to make the 2nd SUBFOLIO to be listed in a right column instead of creating a new row.

Hope I was clear enough and someone can help me.

****Editing the post to show what I'm trying to do/get below*****

```
FOLIOID       FOLIOTYPE   NAME         FOLIONUMBER   SUBFOLIO1     SUBFOLIO2
ad61e75a5bcc  DOORS       JOHN BROWN   2018-01-01    2018-03-01   2018-03-15
```

Comment: I *think* I might understand what you're asking; but it would really help if you include your desired result in table form, in the same way you've shown your actual result

Comment: Make it easier to help you, have much shorter id's in your example.

Comment: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: This can be solved with a dynamic pivot, but taking into account that you are already querying twice a view and joining with a table, maybe that would not be the best solution performance-wise..

Comment: how many subfolioID's can there be? N?  if so then dynamic SQL would be best.  If constant you could use `case statements`, max, and group by to get the desired results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added what I'm trying to get.
Sorry, I didn't pick the id's
A folio can only have a max of 2 subfolios

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  A.FOLIOID
                ,A.FOLIOTYPE
                ,A.NAME
                ,A.FOLIONUMBER
                ,B.FOLIOID AS SUBFOLIOID
                ,B.FOLIONUMBER AS SUBFOLIONUMBER
                ,NVL(D.FOLIOID,'') AS SUBFOLIOID
                ,NVL(D.FOLIONUMBER,'') AS SUBFOLIONUMBER                
FROM VW_FOLIO AS A
INNER JOIN FOLIOREF B ON B.FOLIOPARENTID = A.FOLIOID
INNER JOIN VW_FOLIO C ON C.FOLIOID=B.FOLIOID 
LEFT JOIN FOLIOREF D ON D.FOLIOPARENTID = A.FOLIOID AND D.FOLIOPARENTID <> B.FOLIOPARENTID
WHERE A.FOLIONUMBER='2018-01-01'
```

Comment: It's telling me a NVL is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: It depends what SQL are you using. NVL() is Oracle function. For MSSQL  use ISNULL(). Function COALESCE() is supported my most SQLs and do the trick too. But this functions are not necessary in your statment. You do not need to use it in your statement

Comment: Thank you for the answer back Barkezy. I tried as you suggested and it work but I'm still getting two rows of records. If I would like to get one 1 row. What would I have to do? I'm been trying to fix the joins without luck.

Comment: I was able to get that 1 line by using the top 1 in the select statement because I was getting 2 rows of lines.

Comment: try to remove line with 
INNER JOIN VW_FOLIO C ON C.FOLIOID=B.FOLIOID
i think it should do the trick